# Specifying IndexLabelPlacement at dataPointLevel in a doughnut chart, using canvas.js

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have created a fiddle derived from a fork supplied by the vendor. I would want only the label of the smaller chart segments to be displayed on the outside as shown on the left. This works as expected for a column chart. Is there an easier way to  do this before I start fiddling with the canvas.js source code.

[image]    [image]

To the right is what my chart looks like, using this code

```
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
{

  data: [
  {
    type: "doughnut",
    dataPoints: [
    {  y: 1,indexLabel:"A",indexLabelPlacement:"outside"},
    {  y: 50,indexLabel:"B",indexLabelPlacement:"inside"},
    {  y: 28 ,indexLabel:"C",indexLabelPlacement:"inside"},
    {  y: 31 ,indexLabel:"D",indexLabelPlacement:"inside"},

    ]
  }
  ]
});

chart.render();
```

The fiddle I created is found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/abidmix/8d8oz6ov/)

Comment: A quick scan of the library docs shows `indexLabelPlacement` which lets you put the data labels `inside` or `outside` the donut wedge. But, the API doesn't let you mix the inside / outside options on a single chart. It even resizes the donut based on which option is selected. So yes, you will have to jump into the source code to get your desired "mixed" result.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I agree. I have to accept the inevitable and dissect this library's source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before burying myself deep into canvas.js code , I visited google one more time and stumbled upon a rich library, ZingChart which does exactly what I was looking for(mixing the label positions) without tampering with the library's source code

Snippet for usage

```
$scope.myJson = {

    globals: {
        fontFamily: "MuseoSans-700"
    },
    type: 'pie',
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    plot: {
        detach: false,
        "slice": 55,
        "shadow": 0,
        refAngle: -90,
        valueBox: {
            fontColor: "black",
            fontSize: 16,
            connector: {
                lineWidth: 1,
                height: "50px"

            },
            rules: [
              {
                  rule: "%v > 30",
                  placement: "in",
                  offsetR: 1

              },
              {
                  rule: "%v <= 30",
                  placement: "out"
              }
            ]
        }
    },
series: [
      { "values": [32], "text": "A", backgroundColor: "#c4f0ac" },
      { "values": [32], "text": "B", backgroundColor: "#FF9097" },
      { "values": [1], "text": "C", backgroundColor: "#FF9097" },
      { "values": [1], "text": "D", backgroundColor: "#FF9097" },
      { "values": [1], "text": "NS", backgroundColor: "#bcbcbc" }
        ]
```

And the resulting chart was like this

[image]